How to debug versioned transaction
Do web3js have some analog for .sendAndConfirmTransaction(), but for versioned transactions? I have tried to get transaction status by .getSignatureStatus(), but some times transaction didn't got sent, but without any errors. I need to "debug" versioned transactions.

Versioned & legacy transaction are sent the same way. If your problem is transactions are failing, it would be helpful to see your code.

@Ahri My transactions is not failing, they're just can't get to chain? I don't see new transaction on a solscan and can't get transaction by signature.

I see - Does this answer your question? Transaction sended but cannot be found in blockexplorer If not, please add your code.
